# How to extract from PAX archive to current directory.?

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

I have a PAX archive what I want to extract into the current directory, using the directory structure in the archive. I have tried the following command:

```
JBSP03:/u/jsdbsp/jbsp03:cd /usr/lpp/sel/selcopy
JBSP03:/usr/lpp/sel/selcopy:pax CBL15112.pax.Z
```

but that extracted everything into my root directory:

```
/GIMPAF.XML
/GIMPAF.XSL
/S0001.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.README
/S0002.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.GIMUNZIP
/S0003.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.RIMLIB.pax.Z
/S0005.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.PGMDIR.pax.Z
/SMPHOLD
/SMPHOLD/S0004.CBL.PROD.HOLDDATA.pax.Z
/SMPPTFIN
/SMPPTFIN/S0006.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.PRODDATA.pax.Z
/SMPPTFIN/S0007.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.AZZS330.SMPMCS.pax.Z
```

If I just list the contents of the archive:

```
JBSP03:/usr/lpp/sel/selcopy:pax -f CBL15112.pax.Z
/GIMPAF.XML
/GIMPAF.XSL
/S0001.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.README
/S0002.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.GIMUNZIP
/S0003.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.RIMLIB.pax.Z
/S0005.CBL.PROD.CBL15112.PGMDIR.pax.Z
```

I see that every file is specified as being on the root directory. Does this prevent me from extracting to a directory of my choice?

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think the leading / on all the filenames indicates that they've been archive with an absolute path, rather than a relative path. Pax will therefore, by default, extract them to exactly the same path i.e. the root. Pax doesn;t seem to have a simply 'extract to a specified directory' option, so I'd have to use the -s option to change the filename being extracted onthe fly. In this case I'd want to change the leading '/' to '/usr/lpp/sel/selcopy', perhaps with

```
-s [^/[/usr/lpp/sel/selcopy/[
```

taking advantage of the fact the pax allows the use of deliminators other than '/' to simplify the expression. This also works when just listing the contents of the archive, so you can test your substitution before actually doing it.

Comment: Just found this : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119981/extracting-to-a-directory-other-than-the-current-directory-with-pax-archiver